# When I login to Docker Nexus 3 private registry, I get 404 error

Tags: docker, private, docker-registry, nexus3

I am working in a closed environment, and I need to login to a private Nexus3 registry. 
I have setup the daemon.json with the insecure-registries option. 
I can ping the server, telnet the port and curl the endpoint.
I can login to Nexus3 UI with my credentials.

However, the docker login command shows this:

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://servername:16003/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

Is it an issue with Docker 19.3.01? On other machines with Docker 18.x.x, the login works.

Nexus 3.12.1-01
Docker 19.03.1 
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)

Comment: Is 16003 the port you configured for your specific docker registry? If yes, what happens if you `curl http://servername:16003/` from the host running your docker daemon? You should typically get an 'http error 400: this is not a docker command'. If you get something else (200 with content or 404) you have a configuration issue that you need to sort out.

Comment: Yes, that's the port I configured. And I get the "this is not a docker command" response as you said.

Comment: Not sure this is related to your current problem but worth a try... did you activate the `Docker Bearer Token Realm` in admin > security > Realms ?

Comment: Yes, it is activated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this very same issue and I haven't found a way out... Any search on the internet leads to the very same comments, like "set a connector port", but I'm using a dedicated port and the port is correctly published (5050 btw).... still no way to login via http (yes, not https, I have the host listed among insecure registries) and I get this damn 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59015641/5158269) answer solved the issue for me. Especially the part:

> did not work for me until I created the file

> `/etc/default/docker`

> and put the line

> `DOCKER_OPTS="--config-file=/etc/docker/daemon.json"`

Only then the insecure-registry-setting was really active.