# Logging into GitHub Container Registry fails with HTTP/HTTPS error

Tags: macos, docker, github

I'm trying to push a container to GHCR that I've built with Docker locally. [GitHub's documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry) suggests that I put a Personal Access Token (PAT) with appropriate permissions in an environment variable and then have Docker log into GHCR like this:

```sh
$ echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u USERNAME --password-stdin
```

My username is correct, `$CR_PAT` is definitely in the environment and being returned from the echo request. My token has the `write:packages` and `read:packages` permissions GitHub recommends. And yet when I run the above, it fails with:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://gchr.io/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Putting this string into Google finds no exact matches, and the only hits are talking about [private registries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674004/docker-repository-server-gave-http-response-to-https-client/54190375). Which isn't relevant, I don't think, since I'm trying to use GCHR.

I'm on macOS 10.15. I'm running Docker 20.10.5, installed using Docker Desktop.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your error message contains a typo. It should be `ghcr.io` (GitHub Container Registry) instead of `gchr.io`.

Comment: That's solved it! If you add an answer to the question, I'll accept it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't post this as an answer if I hadn't fallen (several times, actually) into the same pit myself. The error message contains a typo, it should be `ghcr.io` (GitHub Container Registry) instead of `gchr.io`.