# Error in pulling Dockerfile from docker registry

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I have a nexus docker registry that up until today worked great.
Today whenever I try to pull image form the registry i get the following error:

```
Get https://nexus-host:8083/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

In my docker daemon file under /etc/docker/daemon.json file i have configures my insecure registry as such:

```
{"insecure-registries": ["nexus-host:8083"]}
```

As I said until today id had worked perfectly and now it works fr a short period of time after I restart the docker daemon.

Would really appreciate your help,
Alon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker repository server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674004/docker-repository-server-gave-http-response-to-https-client)

Comment: @IshtiyaqHusain OP says that they expect the registry to be insecure, so no, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: As @HansKilian said, unfortunatelly it does not answer my question since i have configured it as insecure-registry already.

Comment: Please provide the output of `docker info` when the pull is working, and also when it fails.

Comment: Since yesterday my problem is different, even restart to docker daemon not helping.
When displaying docker info it does not seem to read the insecure-registry in the config file.
it always shows 127.0.0.0/8 instead of configured "nexus-host:8083"