# kubelet Failed to pull image from local nexus registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nexus

Hell Guys,

I have  K8s cluster which contains 3 nodes ( 1 master and 2 workers) , I deployed nexus I can push and pull without any issue (from the 2 workers), but when I tried to create a deployment using  the image which is located in nexus
: `NEXUS_URL:NEXUS_PORT/image_name:tagname`

```
spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: nexus-registry-key
      containers:
      - name: container-name
        image: NEXUS_URL:NEXUS_PORT/image_name:tagname
```

I noticed that the kublet **Failed** to pull image, and it send HTTPS request to nexus  `https://NEXUS_URL:NEXUS_PORT/v2/image_name/manifests/tagname`

which it gives this error message

rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image `NEXUS_URL:NEXUS_PORT/image_name:tagname` failed to resolve reference  `NEXUS_URL:NEXUS_PORT/image_name:tagname` failed to do request: Head
`https://NEXUS_URL:NEXUS_PORT/v2/image_name/manifests/tagname`  http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

any help guys please and **thank you in advance**

Comment: Looks like your image is hosted in a HTTP server so you could add that to `insecure-registries` as shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674004/docker-repository-server-gave-http-response-to-https-client

Comment: @viggnah thank you for your reply, but as I mentioned in the post that i can pull/push using docker (I already setup the daemon.json file in each node ), problem comes when I run the deployment in k8s,  the Kublet failed to pull image from Nexus but if you pull the image using docker pull "NEXUS_URL:NEXUS_PORT/image_name:tagname" it works

Comment: i have the same problem, did you solve it? can you tell me how?