# docker build with insecure-registries stopped working in Docker 23

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I use custom Docker registries for development and have *insecure-registries* set in /etc/docker/daemon.json. Everything worked in Docker 20.10.

However, version 23.0.1 won't allow me to `docker build` (in the Dockerfile, FROM pulls from my insecure Docker registry), it fails with message: "http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"

I've noticed it can be overriden by setting
`export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0`
to use legacy builder. buildx is a default builder in Docker 23.

`docker pull` works correctly in this version, just the build fails.

Any ideas what to set? Just to be sure: I don't want to set up certificates, but just ignore the SSL warnings.

Comment: you can try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/59015641/4796394

Comment: @antoniomerlin This looked promising, but unfortunately no change. I've been playing around with the BuildKit setup, but so far also unsuccessfully. But I'm probably just doing something wrong.

Comment: @MichalŠpondr can you maybe mark my answer as accepted? The bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a [bug in BUILDKIT](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/1642) which ignores insecure registries setting.

Until then you can either downgrade or turn off the BUILDKIT using

> export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0

or by setting

> BUILDKIT_NO_CLIENT_TOKEN=true

Comment: Thank you sir, this helped a lot when doing gitlab-ci-local stuff.