# helm cant pull image from private repository (nexus3): http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

i am trying to pull image from private registry and i get this error:

i created a namespace called myrelease,
my helm command from my chart folder:

```
helm install myrelease -n myrelease .
```

> http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

i have made all changes required for docker to accept insecure registries.

first of all, i edit every /etc/docker/daemon.json on all nodes to:

```
{
    "features": {
       "buildkit": false
    },
    "insecure-registries" : [ "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8082" ]
}
```

then i tried to login to my repo via:

```
docker login myrepo
```

**and i SUCCEEDED.**

when i try to install my helm chart, i did this configurations:

created templates/secret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.imageCredentials.name }}
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ template "imagePullSecret" . }}
```

i edited the templates/_helper.tpl file:

```
//added to the end of the file:
{{- define "imagePullSecret" }}
{{- with .Values.imageCredentials }}
{{- printf "{\"auths\":{\"%s\":{\"username\":\"%s\",\"password\":\"%s\",\"email\":\"%s\",\"auth\":\"%s\"}}}" .registry .username .password .email (printf "%s:%s" .username .password | b64enc) | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and in my values.yaml i do:

```
image:
  repository: xx.xx.xx.xx:8082/helloworldwar
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: "11"
imageCredentials:
  name: nexuscreds
  registry: xx.xx.xx.xx:8082/helloworld
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx
  email: xxxx@gmail.com
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: nexuscreds
```

in docker info command i have my insecure repo listed:

```
 Insecure Registries:
  xx.xx.xx.xx:8082
  127.0.0.0/8
```

and i still getting the error:

> http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Answer (score 0):

http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client this error is due to not allocating the proper insecure Registries in the docker daemon.

> ```
>  Insecure Registries:
>   xx.xx.xx.xx:8082
>   127.0.0.0/8
> ```

Seems to be  you haven't set the Docker Daemon right as per the above insecure registries. `127.0.0.0/8` this shouldn’t be in Insecure Registries and also You are using a linux server and added the Windows syntax to it.

So, Try to add the below highlighted linux syntax and line  to Docker's daemon.json file and restart the Docker Daemon:

Syntax format:  `{"insecure-registries":["host:port"]}`

```
  add this line : {"insecure-registries":["http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8082"]}
```

The host is the hostname of the server hosting my docker registry and port is the port where the docker registry is available and then restart docker daemon by doing:

```
$ sudo service docker restart
```

Refer to the documents [Configure the Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#configure-the-docker-daemon) and [Configure Docker with a configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#configure-docker-with-a-configuration-file) for additional info.

Edit :

```
{
    "features": {
       "buildkit": false
    },
    {"insecure-registries" : [ "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8082" ]}
}
```

Comment: I didnt understand the difference between daemon.json i set, and what you set, what is the difference between windows and linux? It’s a jason..

Comment: For Linux servers in the daemon.json file you need to add the Curly bases at start and end of the syntax as shown above in answer. In Windows servers we don't add curly bases as you are given. Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674004/) for more information.

Comment: Sorry, but still didnt understand you. I added curly brases at the start and end if file…read again and carefully my description..

Comment: @michael : Kindly check on the edit part in the answer and let me know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: ok i tried, giving me file syntax error on systemctl restart docker

Comment: i think the way i wrote it is right!

Comment: also see that docker pull <private_repo> is working fine!

Comment: As per this [Offical doc](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#deploy-a-plain-http-registry), You need to give a full domain like `"http://myregistrydomain.com"` and have a try or else Just give only IP address and Port instead of full domain and try. As per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71051880/19230181) try to do some changes mentioned in `Configure URL as HTTP` : They have given as `"buildkit": true`  Try this three workarounds one by one and let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: the same....the kubernetes pull still goes for https

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Seeing the same issue

Comment: @michael : Is this issue resolved? if yes, can you post as a solution. I would like to know the solution for this case to know what was actually we are lagging with to clear this error.